# Running code through functions

Tags: programming

I am making a led cube where sequential lighting is used. So basically i need to repeat my commands for a given time. After much reasearch nothing turned up so decided to ask here.

---

Here is the code i need to reproduce in a working format

```
void loop(){
  runfor(500){
    DigitalWrite(5,HIGH);   //this is the command to be executed in other 
                            //function
  }
}
void runfor(uint32_t duration){
  int timer = millis();
  while((millis()-timer)<=duration){
  //DigitalWrite(5,HIGH); will execute here
  }
}
```

So basically DigitalWrite(or any other code if used) will be repeatedly executed for 500 milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** due to misunderstanding the question.

If you want to be able to pass instructions into a function, you will have to have a function for each set of instructions (that is, you cannot pass arbitrary statements as a function parameter), and then you adjust your `runfor()` function to accept a pointer-to-a-function parameter.

```
typedef void (*callback_function)(void);  // defining the type here makes the code easier to read when used in other places.

void runfor(uint32_t duration, callback_function patternCode){
  uint32_t timer = millis();
  while ((millis()-timer)<=duration) {
    //get these commands from caller function
    patternCode();
  }
}

void pattern1() {
  // Light pattern #1
}

void pattern2() {
  // Light pattern #2
}

void setup() {
  // Setup code
}

void loop() {
  runfor(1000, pattern1);
  runfor(2000, pattern2);
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Your starting pseudo-code is nearly there.

```
void runfor(uint32_t duration){
  uint32_t timer = millis();
  while ((millis()-timer)<=duration) {
    //get these commands from caller function
  }
}
```

Changes I made:

1. change `int` to `uint32_t` to accommodate all possible values of `millis()`.
2. change `for` keyword to `while`, which is the correct keyword for the loop type you want.
3. added semicolon after your `timer` assignment, per C syntax.

Comment: Im sorry, I'll edit my post. Thanks for informing!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: jose can u c  I mean a reform to the code so it basically 'accepts' function from say loop() and runs the commands in the ensuing { } braces. Also can you please post comments on my questions to the question comments so that others can understand?

Comment: Your timer variable wants to be `uint32_t`.

Comment: @A.Shetye The code sample provided in the answer does what you are asking. Your initial example in the question was very close to correct already!

Comment: I suppose I am misunderstood. The // part here is not any sample code. So if i do **runfor(50){ <place code here}** from say loop(), it should run the given code for 50 milliseconds. So i suppose my current code cant do that?

Comment: I changed my answer, now that I understand you.